# How to save&load a keras model with a custom loss function which depends on class variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm creating a LSTM based Variational Auto Encoder. I have created my own custom loss function where I am using two different class variables, `pos_weight` and `kl_cof`. `kl_cof` is changing it's value every epoch.

```
 class LSTM_VAE(object):
     
     def __init__(..,pos_weight=None)
     
         ..
         self.kl_cof = K.variable(0.5)
         self.pos_weight = pos_weight
         self.autoencoder = None
         ....

         def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
            xent_loss = K.mean(x*-K.log(x_decoded_mean)*self.pos_weight+(1-x)*-K.log(1-x_decoded_mean))
            kl_loss = ....
            return xent_loss + K.get_value(self.kl_cof)*kl_loss
            ....
          self.autoencoder.compile(optimizer='Adam',
                     loss=vae_loss,
                     metrics=['accuracy'])

    def train_model(self,X_train,X_val,batch_size,epochs):
          cbk = LambdaCallback(....)
          print_weights = LambdaCallback(....)
          self.autoencoder.fit(x=X_train, y=X_train,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,callbacks=[self.checkpointer,cbk,print_weights],validation_data=(X_val,X_val))
    ....
```

When self.autoencoder has finished training, the model is saved as a 'lstm_vae.h5' file. But when I try to run

```
  lstm_vae=keras.models.load_model('lstm_vae.h5')
```

it throws an `ValueError: Unknown loss function:vae_loss`.

After doing some research in other threads, it says that I should pass the loss function inside custom_object as such

```
 lstm_vae=keras.models.load_model('lstm_vae.h5',custom_object={'loss':vae_loss})
```

But once again it throws `ValueError: Unknown loss function:vae_loss` since I have the loss function defined inside the LSTM_VAE class, this is because the loss function is using LSTM_VAE class variables.

So how do I correctly load the model when I am using this custom loss function?

Comment: It should be custom_object={'vae_loss' : vae_loss}

Comment: Same results. NameError: name 'vae_loss' is not defined

Comment: I suppose I would have to define it ouside the LSTM_VAE class, but how would I then access kl_cof, pos_weight (class variables)?

Comment: You can just make a new instance of the LSTM_VAE class and pass the loss, or if you just want to load the model to make predictions, you can pass a loss that does not do anything

Comment: So if I would make a new instance of the LSTM_VAE, should I create function which returns the loss and then pass that? Like custom_object={'vae_loss':LSTM_VAE().pass_loss()}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
model = load_model("path/to/model.h5", compile=False)
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=.01)

def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    xent_loss = K.mean(x*-K.log(x_decoded_mean)*self.pos_weight+(1-x)*-   K.log(1-x_decoded_mean))
    kl_loss = ....
    return xent_loss + K.get_value(self.kl_cof)*kl_loss

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=vae_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I had the same issue and loading the model uncompiled and then defining the loss before recompiling was the solution that worked for me